# How to Decrypt encrypted database value with salt and password

Tags: java, security, encryption

I have the Salt generated using `org.jasypt.salt.FixedStringSaltGenerator`. I have the password. The algorithm is `PBEWithMD5AndDES`. Encrypting the content with Jasypt protocol.

Can anyone please tell me the way I can decrypt the content using a tool or java code.

Comment: Generating salt is an irreversible process.

Comment: This is a Fixed Salt. I have it and also the password. This is my testing system

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encrypt and decrypt data in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319496/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-data-in-java)

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319496/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-data-in-java - "not a real question" too but the link even has an answer.